# Apigility call created Rest Service from Controller

Tags: zend-framework2

have created a Rest Service "User" with Apigility.

I have to call this Service within another Controller with Params.

The Rest calling URL via Http is: http://rest.local/user.

My only Idea would to call the REST URL via Zend\Http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling from directly in the PHP environment, instead of creating another http transmission?

Since the codebase is all in one ZF2 instance.. just reference the class to the Controller and call it as you normally would.

be careful that any filtering and expected pre-controller things your codebase is doing (like in the routing) are either there.. or not implicitly expected

EDIT:  the proper Zend way is to inject an instance of the other service's class into the original service..  ie Dependency Injection .. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/quickstart.di.html